# How to attach a click event to an animated button in ios

Tags: ios5, uibutton, core-animation

I am having a moveable button and would like to execute a method when the user click on that button - is that possible in ios?

I have write the following code but the animation needs to be finished in order to be able to trigger that function:

```
[arrowButton addTarget:self action:@selector(presentMainWindow) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


[UIView animateWithDuration:kAnimationDuration
                          delay:.2f
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut 
                     animations:
     ^{
         [arrowButton setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(kButtonShift, 0)];
         [arrowButton setFrame:CGRectMake(arrowButton.frame.origin.x + kButtonShift, arrowButton.frame.origin.y, arrowButton.frame.size.width, arrowButton.frame.size.height);
     } 
                     completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found out that you can simply add the option **UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction** to the animation to handle both the animation and the interaction:

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:kAnimationDuration
                          delay:.2f
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                     animations:
     ^{
         [arrowButton setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(kButtonShift, 0)];
    } 
                     completion:nil];
```

Comment: Note to myself and others :-) u can freeze the animation then by just going this: [CATransaction begin];
    [_arrowButton.layer removeAllAnimations];
    [CATransaction commit];

Answer (score 0):

as long as the animation is only an effect what you can see 
and not can touch you can only click the button while animating if you make your own animation like this

i dont know if this is the best solution but it is an working solution.

```
- (IBAction)startanimation:(id)sender {

    old = CGPointMake(arrowButton.frame.origin.x,arrowButton.frame.origin.x);
    [self ani];


}
- (void)ani {
    NSLog(@"ani1");

    if (arrowButton.frame.origin.x < old.x + kButtonShift ) {

        NSTimer*myTimer;

        myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:kTimeInterval/kButtonShift*4 target:self selector:@selector(ani2) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

}
}
- (void)ani2 {
    NSLog(@"ani2");

    arrowButton.frame = CGRectMake((arrowButton.frame.origin.x + 1), arrowButton.frame.origin.y, arrowButton.frame.size.width, arrowButton.frame.size.height);
    [self ani];

}
```

Comment: hi thanks for your answer! While it works with ur approach i find out that you can use the option UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction in the animation so no need to write ur own animation actually!